# How to get input from website to field.integer() in Python Odoo

Tags: python, web, input, odoo, odoo-14

On the Website View,

How to get the value of "nbr1" field and use it in Python ?

Does someone have an example or documentation, please ?

[image]

**template.xml**

```
  <template id="biography">
        <t t-call="website.layout">
            <t t-set="title">bio</t>
            <div class="oe_structure">
                <div class="container">
                    <h3 t-field="person.name"/>
                    <p>Last modified: <i t-field="person.write_date"/></p>                  
                    <p>nbr1 : <input type="number" name="nbr1"/></p>
                    <p>Direct copy of nbr1 : <h3 t-field="person.result"/></p>
                </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="oe_structure"/>
        </t>
    </template>
```

**model.py**

```
name = fields.Char()
nbr1 = fields.Integer()
result = fields.Integer(compute="_compute_total")    

@api.depends('nbr1')
def _compute_total(self):
    for record in self:
        record.result = self.nbr1
```

Comment: @onchange events triggerred by the webclient, a very complicated javascript framework of odoo. to do this in front end you need to do your self using Javascript skills. And you question is not clear at all

Comment: @CharifDZ sorry, I would like to get the information put by people on the website form. In this way I can use this information in an equation. For example, if someone enter a "4" number I would like to get this number in nbr1 field

Answer (score 0):

OnChange and compute field are not the same.

Change your code into this .

```
@api.depends('nbr1')
def _compute_total(self):
    for record in self:
        record.result = 2*self.nbr1
```

If you want your computed field to store in database,

```
result = fields.Integer(compute="_compute_total", store=True)
```

Comment: Thank you Khay, I didn't know for the "store=True". But what I would like is to get the input from an user, through an input form. Then after I can use this valu on an equation. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Please try removing ```compute="_compute_total"``` from the field and use ```@api.onchange('nbr1')```.

Comment: I did it but its not working, then I added more detail in the question and tried new thing but still not working